# Any other way to define an environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables

I'm quite new to Linux. Debian Wheezy is now running on my Laptop (64 bits).

I recently installed Oracle 11g R2 database for evaluation purpose, and defined environment variables (such as `ORACLE_SID`) through a script `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh`. This works fine, but for the "oracle" user.

I change user by `su - oracle`.
The value of `ORACLE_SI`D is different from the one specified in the `/etc/profile.d/oracle.sh` file.
As the oracle user has no file (such as `.bash_profile`, `.profile` etc.) in its home directory, where can this value come from?

What is the overloading sequence of environment variables?

Comment: yes, as debian user you have a hard time reading man pages with an invariant section. use google for `man bash`. you will find your answers there

Comment: What's the login shell of the oracle user? Is there `pam_env` in the PAM configuration for `su`? Is there a `~oracle/.pam_environment` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ever set's the environment variable last wins. So it doesn't really matter, I would just set the variable in the oracle user's `$HOME/.bashrc` file towards the bottom.

The file `$HOME/.bashrc` is the key file which sources files such as `/etc/bashrc` and the files under `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` for example. So I would just set `ORACLE_SID=whatever` in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

#### Debugging Tip

If you want to see what's going on you can debug your login like so:

```
su - oracle -c "env SHELLOPTS=xtrace bash"
```

With the above command you can follow along as the different files are sourced by bash:

```
...
...
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/less.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/less.sh
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ']'
+++ export 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
+++ LESSOPEN='||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/qt.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/qt.sh
+++ '[' -z /usr/lib64/qt-3.3 ']'
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh
+++ '[' -z '4.1.7(1)-release' ']'
+++ complete -o filenames -F __udisks udisks
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vim.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+++ '[' -n '4.1.7(1)-release' -o -n '' -o -n '' ']'
+++ '[' -x //usr/bin/id ']'
++++ //usr/bin/id -u
+++ '[' 0 -le 200 ']'
+++ return
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which2.sh ']'
...
...
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, a /home/oracle/.profile file was executed when I switched user. This file has been created at install, and provided the latest value for ORACLE_SID variable. There was no mysterious origin for this value ! Thanks for your help !